# Faux / Synthetic Italics in React Native

Tags: react-native

Quick question, is there a way (perhaps plugin) for a font family with no italics variant to be italicized by using `fontStyle: 'italic'`? I'm planning to use Lexend and Readex pro in my app, but can't seem to find a way to include an italics style of the font in the app.

here's a snippet of the styles code of a link in the app:

this is without italics
`link: { fontFamily: 'Lexend', color: colors.main_color_80, },`
[without italics, the font of the link is Lexend, as requested in its fontFamily attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcqzB.jpg)

and this is with italics
`link: { fontStyle: 'italic', fontFamily: 'Lexend', color: colors.main_color_80, },`
[with italics, the font instead changes to the default font, because Lexend has no italics variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8lCr.jpg)

Comment: You create a slanted font version in most font editors (fontForge-free, fontlab, glyphs etc.) But I rather recommend selecting another font family offering true italics